# Moved from sql server to snowflake finding case sensitive collation issue

Tags: collation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

in snowflake it searches data with case sensitiveness while in sql server it used to search with case insensitiveness i changed database level collation with  below command

```
ALTER DATABASE IF EXISTS  powerdb SET  COLLATION = 'en-ci'
```

but it did not help is there any other way to achive case insensitiveness

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways really.

one of them is using ILIKE for your string comparison: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/ilike.html

another one is setting up collation at column level:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/collation.html
- but please note that not all of the string functions are supported on collated columns

also you can use COLLATION functions (also described in the link below) or set it on database level with account-level parameter of DEFAULT_DDL_COLLATION = 'en-ci'

everything depends on what you want to achieve really...

Comment: i am migrating complete sql serevr database to snowflake which has lots of sql procedure and sql queries which will be running on snowflake same way, but is there any setting on database level which can setup the same behaviour of sql queries which i used to get from sql server.

Comment: DEFAULT_DDL_COLLATION = 'en-ci' on account level?